# Safari 15 on macOS not connecting to unsecured http sites

Tags: macos, safari

UPDATE (2022-12-23): turns out the issue is caused by ISP (more specifically, all ISP's in Egypt at the time of writing), and everything works as expected when I'm connected over VPN.

This is a weird issue that has been going on since the release of Safary 15.

It does not connect to any website over http, even if the site redirects to https. It simply times out and says “couldn’t connect.”

I’ve tried:

- deleting cooking and site data.
- clearing history.
- disabling extensions.
- resetting HSTS, and deleting safari folder.
- macOS safe mode.
- testing on an entirely new macbook and a clean install of macOS

I haven't tried reinstalling OS <s>or creating a new user</s> yet, because I cannot do that at the moment due to time constraints.

EDIT 1: Problem persists with newly created user.

Safari 15 has been doing that since its release on BigSur and still on Monterey.

It doesn’t matter if I open website from address bar or click a link in a page.

I think it has to do with the new HTTPS redirection.

It’s really frustrating, any suggestions?

P.S.

- I don’t have a proxy, it’s a home network, and I do not use VPN.
- I does not work no matter what network i’m connected to, and the same websites open fine in firefox.
- Some sites are not operating over https, some have both and redirects http to https, but if I click a link or attempt to open URL with http, it does not open. I have to copy the link and open in another browser.
- Some websites—especially academic—do not have SSL, so it's really important for me to have it working over unsecured HTTP.
- I do not have Adguard or any other safe guard apps that might be manipulating my connection routing the traffic elsewhere.

EDIT 2: [Wireshark dump (Safari rquest)](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArhBsE1xR6uIg-gkDVYdOSqmgPt09A?e=WJMGMA)

EDIT 3: [Wireshark dump (Firefox rquest)](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArhBsE1xR6uIg-glBglDlASP5boErA?e=qeve7E)

NOTE: Sites work fine on Safari on iOS, on same network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Given your update and the Wireshark dump I requested, it is clear that the problem is not with your Safari browser. The browser does send the request for the site in the HTTP protocol (non-encrypted). However, it never receives a reply from the server.

You need to look at any software you have installed that could interfere with network requests, devices on your local network (routers, firewall, VPN gateways, etc) as well as what your internet provider does to your traffic. If you have a secondary computer, tablet, etc it would be worth testing that on the same network.

**OLD ANSWER**

I'm not sure I'm convinced that this is caused by the automatic HTTPS upgrade (I cannot see why it would) - but if you believe this to be so, I would suggest trying to disable that feature.

First you need to enter Safari Preferences, click on the `Advanced` tab and then put a checkmark for `Show Develop menu in menu bar`.

Then from the `Develop` menu in Safari, under the `Experimental Features` submenu, you can disable `Automatic HTTPS Upgrade`.

If you haven't got this option, I would try installing [Safari Technology Preview](https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/) and try the same!

Comment: I believe it has to do with HTTPS upgrade because "popular" sites e.g. twitter.com redirect fine from http->https, other sites, which also implement redirection, do not work. So I think it lookup HSTS list and does not see the sites there.

Also, the Safari option for the "Automatic HTTPS Upgrade" is no longer there since the release of Safari 15. That is the issue, I would've disabled it but I can't.

Comment: Also, this only happens with HTTP connection, if I manually switch protocol to HTTPS, the websites work fine. Which is another reason to think this has to do with automatic HTTPS upgrade.

Comment: You need to install the Preview as mentioned to get the menu I think - or downgrade Safari (a lot harder unless you have a backup).

Comment: I don’t follow your logic around why this would be caused by the HTTPS upgrade feature, but it is of course possible that you’re running into some rare bug there. You could try installing Wireshark and see what the browser sends to the server and if you get a reply at all.

Comment: menu is not available in Technology Preview as well. Downgrading or re-installing the OS is not a option for me at the moment, and not really a long-term solution.

Comment: I will check with wireshark and report back.

Comment: Also, I find the reasons I stated pretty reasonable to think the issue is caused by HTTPS upgrade, and specifically HSTS preload, because it works with all popular websites and not any other, which indicates that it "looks up" the sites in the HSTS preload list.


Of course, this is a speculation after all, not saying it definitely is the issue.

Comment: I don’t think it’s reasonable, but that’s my opinion as a professional. You’re entitled to your opinion of course. I’m just saying that I would keep my options open and search broader for the cause. Now you’re saying that some sites actually do work or what? As far as I understood the question, I thought you said that no http site worked? For sites on the HSTS preload list they will never load as http, so they’re not really relevant in searching for your problems with http.

Comment: The whole point of the HSTS preload list is that these sites will only be accessed over TLS/SSL/https. I think you should continue with Wireshark as that would give valuable insight into the actual cause of the problem.

Comment: I appreciate your opinion! I'm merely stating what I think, which can absolutely be wrong.

"The whole point of the HSTS preload list is that these sites will only be accessed over TLS/SSL/https."

I realize that, and that is exactly why I think this is the issue. 

Most sites i'm trying to visit over HTTP _do_ have HTTPS implemented, and even redirect to https when visited over http. Except for popular sites.

For example: if I try http://stackoverflow.com or http://twitter.com it redirects fine. But I i visit http://airliners.net it does not.

Comment: Both sites work fine in firefox (both redirect to https.)

Also, by saying some sites are working, I mean: 1- they either work over http (depending on site) if visited on firefox. 2- redirect to https (popular sites work fine on Safari others don't and redirect fine in firefox.)

Comment: I checked Wireshark, not traffic is going to the website I tested with at all.

Comment: Actually, Wireshark shoes requests for the site, sorry. How can I send them here?

I sent request, I see HTTP GET Request in wireshark, then it keeps doing TCP Retransmission for several until it times out.

The requests has: "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1"

Comment: Okay, so now we can conclude that it is not the fault of the browser (unless you’re misreading Wireshark). You need to look at any software you have installed that could interfere with network requests, devices on your local network (routers, firewall, VPN gateways, etc) as well as your internet provider. If you have a secondary computer, tablet, etc it would be worth testing that on the same network.

Comment: The weird thing is that I do not use any firewalls, proxy, or VPN or anything that may intercept connections. And the website works fine in any other browser, and responds to PING and curl.

This only happens in Safari. And if I explicitly open the mentioned websites in HTTPS it works.

Comment: I might be misreading Wireshark. Here is the sequence of packets: First few are SYN/ACK, then HTTP GET, then few TCP Retransmission, then FIN/ACK, then RST/ACK.

I'm not quite sure if I can't make use of this. I've filtered pertinent packets and saved to file, should I send?

Comment: Yes, you could add the dump as a link to the question for example - or a few screenshots. But it seems that the request is being sent from the browser, it goes out the of the network interface, but no reply comes back - that means the problem is external.

Comment: Updated question with wireshark dump.

Comment: You say that it works in other browsers - I think this is news to us. Do you mean that if you open Firefox, Chrome or similar and access the exact same airliners site on HTTP (non-HTTPS) - you can get the site to work? - Without using SSL? - If so, please make a Wireshark dump with that second browser. Then it is possible to compare for differences.

Comment: I have tested airliners.net in Safari with "Automatic HTTPS Upgrade" turned both off and on - it works fine in both cases.

Comment: I'm certain it works with Firefox and Chrome. I know this doesn't make sense, but this is the behavior I'm experiencing. I updated question with Wireshark dump for Firefox request.

Comment: The Firefox dump is quite different, the first packet is over TLS directly, no HTTP request going to the server.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new here. But the comment thread is getting quite long here, should I move it to chat?

Comment: Turns out it is my ISP, everything works fine over a VPN.